# how to make modification in woocommerce function get_discounted_price without change in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on ecommerce site and want to modify this function `get_discounted_price` which is located in  `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php`

What is better way to modify this function without made change in main plugin function?

Comment: Write your own function and find an action to hook to with your function

Comment: @dingo_d sorry but not getting you. can you help me out here?

Comment: Take that function you found, copy it, change it's name a bit, and some functionality you want. Do this in functions php. Then just find the hook where that function is executed in woocommerce, remove it with `remove_action`, and using 'add_action' target the same hook, and just add your function instead like `add_action('the_hook_place_for_function_to_appear', 'your_function_discount');`.

Comment: If you want to modify the discount price then you can do it using "woocommerce_get_discounted_price" filter provided in the function.

Comment: @dingo_d `get_discounted_price` is not used by any hook.it only used in same class like this `$discounted_price = $this->get_discounted_price( $values, $base_price, true );`

Comment: @WisdmLabs actually i want to change some logic of this function.

Comment: Don't think that's possible.